# Notice: Trying to get property 'innertext' of non-object

Tags: php, html, dom

i am trying to get price which is $209.97 by using dom but i am getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property 'innertext' of non-object

This is the HTML Source Code

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">$209.97</span>
```

This is the code i written

```
$price = $html->find("span[class='a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString']",0)->innertext;

echo $price;
```

Comment: Assuming you loaded the HTML correctly, It didn't find it... And what library are you using?

Comment: I am using Simple HTML Dom